# How to read the response from serial port

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial

I'm new with the python language

I have a uart bluetooth dongle, I wrote this code below and the write method works fine because I can see the response using the **gtkterm** software

Code:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 115200
ser.port = '/dev/ttyUSB0'

ser.open()
print(ser.is_open)

ser.write(b'info\r\n')  # get info command 
ser.write(b'scan=00\r\n')  # start scan command
```

The response displayed in **gtkterm** software:

```
Device information
firmware: nrf_dongle
firmware_version: 0.2.5-ba519b3
firmware_build: 20180413-104249
device_name: amine
serial_number: a58f2080352ac55bd1850576df54
mac_address: d1850576df54
device_state: 1
adv_state: 0
scan_state: 0
END

@scan:d1850576df54,20fabb03c064,-71,2,30,0201041aff4c00021570996ffaa2c34f00b776a3852c4bbd790cb90006c2
@scan:d1850576df54,20fabb044b2c,-62,2,30,0201041aff4c000215023f3d601143013582ba2e1e1603bcb9ffff02e5c5
@scan:d1850576df54,20fabb044b51,-54,3,30,0201041aff4c000215023f3d601143013582ba2e1e1603bcb9ffff02c8c5
@scan:d1850576df54,20fabb044b2c,-62,2,30,0201041aff4c000215023f3d601143013582ba2e1e1603bcb9ffff02e5c5
.
.
.
```

So my question is how can I read this data using the pyserial module or any other approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many approaches to this problem. First of all the question is - do you want to implement every detail yourself as an exercise? If so then you can implement a function that will read from the serial port one byte at the time, like so:

```
def readline(port):
    message = ""
    byte = ""
    while True:
        byte = port.read()
        if byte == "\n":
            break
        message += byte
    return message
```

It will stop reading from the port when the newline character is encountered and return the message so far. But be aware that there are some problems here (is the `end-of-line` character always `"\n"`? What if there is a timeout on the `read` function?)

Here is the [link to the documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html?highlight=read#serial.Serial.read) about how the `read` function behaves. Note, that if the `Serial` object has not been set with a timeout the function will block, which means that it will wait for the incoming data from the serial port.

The PySerial documentation is a great source of information on the topic - they also provide an example for using the readline function that takes into account problems connected to the newline differences (end-of-line characters). Here is the example from the docs rewritten for your example:

```
import serial
import io

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 115200
ser.port = '/dev/ttyUSB0'

ser.open()
print(ser.is_open)

sio = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(ser, ser))

sio.write(b'info\r\n')
sio.flush() # it is buffering. required to get the data out *now*
response = sio.readline()
print(response)
```

I strongly suggest to look at the `miniterm.py` module that is supplied with the PySerial module. Although it might be quite hard at first it is in my opinion a good source of learning material to get accustomed with this library.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer